# Why is Flow Type not inferring the correct Generic Type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

We have been trying to annotate our Higher Order Components in React in our codebase with Flow, without much success.

We have

- `adapt` Higher order component which accepts an adapter as an argument.
- `adaptDataProp` which accepts a dataAdapter which will only be invoked on the `props.data` object

Here is the implementation without Flow implemented

```js
function adapt(adapter) {
    return (Component) {
        return (props) => <Component {...adapter(props)} />;
    };
}

function adaptDataProp(dataAdapter) {
    function adapter(inputProps) {
        const { data, ...rest } = inputProps;
        return ({ ...dataAdapter(data), ...rest });
    }

    return adapt(adapter);
}

 const TestFunction = ({ moo, className }) => <div className={className}>{ moo }</div>

const dataAdapter = ({ a }) => ({ moo: a });
const AdaptedTestFunction = adaptDataProp(dataAdapter)(TestFunction);

// rendering
<AdaptedTestFunction data={{ a: 'a' }} className='b' />
```

Below are the test cases we have:

```js
// Test example 1: Should fail as data prop passed in is wrong
<AdaptedTestFunction data={{ b: 'b' }} className='b' /> 

// Test example 2: Should fail as missing className prop
<AdaptedTestFunction data={{ a: 'a' }} />

// Test example 3: Should pass  
<AdaptedTestFunction data={{ a: 'a' }} className='b' />
```

Our flow annotation for the above uses [Generic Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/).

We have `adapt`, `adaptDataProp` in separate files.

```js
// Functional Component for React
type FunctionalComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => ?React$Element<any>;
// Union of Functional Component or a Class React Component
type ComponentDefinition<DefaultProps, Props, State> = FunctionalComponent<Props> | Class<React$Component<DefaultProps, Props, State>>;


type AdaptReturnType<AdaptedProps, Props> = ComponentDefinition<void, AdaptedProps, *> => FunctionalComponent<Props>;

function adapt<
  Props: Object, 
  AdaptedProps: Object
>(adapter: Props => AdaptedProps): AdaptReturnType<AdaptedProps, Props> {
    return (Component: ComponentDefinition<void, AdaptedProps, *>): FunctionalComponent<Props> => {
        return (props: Props) => <Component {...adapter(props)} />;
    };
}

function adaptDataProp<
    Data: Object,
    AdaptedData: ?Object,
    Rest: Object
>(dataAdapter: Data => AdaptedData): 
    AdaptReturnType<
        Rest & AdaptedData,
        Rest & { data: Data }
    > {
    function adapter(inputProps: Rest & { data: Data }): Rest & AdaptedData {
        const { data, ...rest } = inputProps;
        return ({ ...dataAdapter(data), ...rest });
    }

    return adapt(adapter);
}

type Props = {
    moo: string,
    className: string
};

type AdaptedProps = {
   moo: string
};

type Data = {
    a: string
};

const TestFunction = ({ moo, className }: Props) => <div className={className}>{ moo }</div>

const dataAdapter = ({ a }: Data): AdaptedProps => ({ moo: a });
const AdaptedTestFunction = adaptDataProp(dataAdapter)(TestFunction);
```

However, for test example 3, I get the following error:

```js
 const TestFunction = ({ moo, className }: Props) => <div className={className}>{ moo }</div>
                                            ^ property `moo`. Property not found in
 <AdaptedTestFunction data={{ a: 'a' }} className='b' /> 
  ^ props of React element `AdaptedTestFunction`
```

We expect the above to pass because AdaptedTest should only fail if it does not conform to `Rest & { data: Data }`.

Is this an issue with Flow itself or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:** Flow does not infer generic types.
>
> If you want something to have a generic type, annotate it. Otherwise, Flow may infer a type that is less polymorphic than you expect.

via: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/